# 9 divs in a row, want to lose one div at every breakpoint with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I have 9 divs all the same size in one row.  I am using the latest version of bootstrap 3.

How should I code it so that, when making the screen smaller, lose exactly one div at every breakpoint until the screen is mobile size and displays exactly two divs?

With current bootstrap there are I believe four breakpoints, will I have to code my own extra breakpoints using media queries?  How would I do that?  I think I would need about eight breakpoints in total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then just don't use bootstrap!!!, use `float:left` instead, and let the browser decide when to move the overflowing divs to the new line.

Also you could use `display: inline-block;` for the similar effect, while also reaping the benefits of being able to align them(blocks) as text.

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/MohdAbdulMujib/pen/ozWBgB)**

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap by default only has 3 or 4 breakpoints. If you have 9 columns and want to end up with 2, you'll need 7, so best that you write your own queries for these (mobile first).

Personally I'd handle the columns themselves with some custom styles. By using something like the following styles, you'll end up with a set of columns that always fill the row, even if you remove some (or if you don't care too much about backwards compatibility, use flexbox). Note: do not override Bootstrap's classes though.

```
.row {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.column {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Now you just need some media queries that hide the nth-child (will need various selectors).

Answer (score 0):

I personally avoid flexbox, since it not compatible with my custom directive templates. Still you can use the bootstrap 3 and add styles and custom queries to align properly.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id = "itemContainer" class="col-md-1"> One </div>
         ..................
        <div id = "itemContainer" class="col-md-1"> Six </div>
        <div id = "itemContainer" class="col-md-1"> Seven </div>
    </div>
 </div>


#itemContainer {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
  min-width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sripathi007/ddtbdcgb/1/)